# Dynamic DOM not trigger button click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom

Dynamic DOM not trigger button click.

I am using a table structure and apply datatable.net to it. Table populating its row and column data by angularjs and there is also edit or delete button. All are working fine. as soon as i want to implement nested table i just put a hidden td and when we click on expand i dynamically convert td to tr. But dynamically created tr not support any angular event like click etc.
I hope its using bind onclick how we bing "live" onclick of jquery in angularjs.
Please guide us.

Comment: Since you are using angularjs use [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

Comment: If you are ok with not only using angularjs to solve it (since large tables with lots of events is a recepie for slow). I just answered a similar question by creating an npm module for it called GoodTap. Jsbin example: https://jsbin.com/julujekuko/edit?html,output